# In Rune Factory ToD, is there any point to the Cherry Blossom Festival?

Tags: rune-factory-tod

Is there any point to the Cherry Blossom Festival? I feel like I'm only walking around and talking to people, is there something else that I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an [IGN walkthrough](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/119/1199949p1.html),

> You basically have six hours to complete the Cherry Blossom Festival Mini-Game
>   if you speak to James immediately at noon. He will direct you to Odette, who
>   will be found in her Kitchen. You can teleport back to your home to save time.
>
> Odette will tell you that she cannot complete the Festival feast because she is
>   missing three Ingredients. She then will list the Ingredients and ask that you
>   obtain them from specific Villagers. The Ingredients are loaded randomly but
>   the Villagers appear to be the same, at least in the first Year. The Villagers
>   who hold the Ingredients are: Electra, Bismark and James. Each Item is specific
>   to a Character and when you speak to the Character in question, he/she will
>   pretend to have forgotten what is required. You must choose the correct Item
>   from a list of three in each case.
>
> James is easy to find. He will be at his Stall at the Plaza Pavilion throughout
>   the afternoon. Electra should be near the Mansion. It is Bismark who presented
>   a problem for me. Although the Map showed him to be near the Gemini General
>   Store, I could not find him until 4.30 p.m., when he appeared outside the Shop.
>   In any case, that was soon enough to complete the task.
>
> When you return to Odette, you physically must give her all three Items in
>   order to complete the Mini-Game. She then will make you a Cooked Dish using
>   those Ingredients and give it to her. You can eat it, stash it or sell it. That
>   is the extent of the Cherry Blossom Festival in the first Spring.